# Нужен Ваш совет по Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Достался мне интернет-магазин, написанный другими разработчиками на RexFramework (личная разработка компании). Задание - починить пагинатор, в принципе ничего сложного, но тут я столкнулся с проблемой. Пагинатор описан в шаблоне Smarty вот так {$dg}, закрывающего тега нет... В браузере пагинатор выглядит уныло:

```
<div class="dg_pager_container">
    <span>[1]</span>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="dg_pager" page="2">2</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="dg_pager" page="3">3</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="dg_pager" page="4">4</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="dg_pager" page="2">Next</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="dg_pager" page="4">Last</a>
</div>
```

Не могу найти где описывается кастомный Smarty тег {$dg}? Подскажите, пожалуйста, где искать?

Comment: Ищите в php файлах где формируются все данные страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php коде Должна быть строка типа:

```
$smarty->assing('dg', $paginator);
```

в переменной $paginator и будет html который присутствует у вас в вопросе. Переменная $smarty разумеется может называться по другому, но в любом случае она будет экземпляром класса Smarty.